# Laravel problem with file status from database

Tags: php, database, laravel, file

the main idea of this code are to loop the folder (files/), take all files from the folder (*.txt), store file name, vei_code, date to File database table. Then take that file content and store it to Content table and so on. Content and File tables are connected by foreign key. If the all store operation was successful to database, file status will be changed to 1 if not it will be 0 and all that file records will be deleted if file status will be 0. But if I want to find all files from database where status is 0 I getting empty array. Any help will be very useful.
Code:

```
  public function test(){
      try {
        // $url =" www.url.com/".;
        foreach (glob('files/*.txt') as $index => $path) {
            $filename = basename($path, '.txt');
            list($vei_id, $date, $type) = explode('_', $filename);
            $filename = $vei_id.'_'.$date;
            $content = array();

            $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd+', $date)->format('Y-m-d');

            // storing data to database
            $fileDB = new File();
            $fileDB->name = $filename;
            $fileDB->vei_id = $vei_id;
            $fileDB->file_date = $date;
            $fileDB->save();


            // files are csv files, read them line by line with fgetcsv
            if ( false !== $handle = fopen($path, 'rb') ) {
                while ( false !== $fields = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ';') ) {
                    array_pop($fields);
                    $content[] = $fields;
                }
                fclose($handle);
                try {
                  foreach ($content as $key => $data) {
                    $input = $fileDB->Contents()->create([
                      'file_id' => $fileDB->id,
                      // hard coded value, in the future I will create this record from other DB place
                      'vei_sn' => '23333',
                      'op_date' => $data[0],
                      'con_type' => $data[1],
                      'op_name' => $data[2],
                      'ecu_name' => $data[3],
                      'ecu_name2' => $data[4],
                    ]);
                  }

                  // THERE THE PROBLEM STARTS

                  //check if input was successful, change file status from 0 to 1
                  if ($input) {
                    $fileDB->status = '1';
                    $fileDB->save();
                  }

                  // find file status where status = 0
                  $fileFails = File::where($fileDB->status, '=', '0')->get();
                  print_r($fileFails);
                } catch (Exception $e) {

                }
                echo '<pre>', print_r($content, true), '</pre>';
            }
          }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
      }
```

This is how look like my file structure:

```
09/02/2020 11:03:58;OBD;FLASHRead;MCM;2;;
09/02/2020 11:05:09;OBD;EEPROMRead;MCM;2;;
09/02/2020 11:10:06;OBD;FLASHRead;ACM;2;;
09/02/2020 11:11:16;OBD;EEPROMRead;ACM;2;;
11/02/2020 08:31:36;OBD;EEPROMWrite;ACM;2.1;;
11/02/2020 08:36:07;OBD;EEPROMWrite;ACM;2.1;;
11/02/2020 08:42:55;OBD;FLASHWrite;ACM;2.1;;
12/02/2020 05:57:48;OBD;EEPROMRead;ACM;2;;
12/02/2020 06:05:00;OBD;FLASHWrite;ACM;2;;
12/02/2020 06:06:08;OBD;EEPROMRead;MCM;2;;
```

This is my File database table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('file_date');
            $table->integer('status')->default('0');
            $table->string('vei_id', 8);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is my Content database table:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('file_id');
            $table->integer('vei_sn');
            $table->dateTime('op_date');
            $table->string('con_type');
            $table->string('op_name');
            $table->string('ecu_name');
            $table->string('ecu_name2');
            $table->integer('tokens')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('file_id')
                  ->references('id')->on('files')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a slight syntax error here:

```
$fileFails = File::where($fileDB->status, '=', '0')->get();
```

You want to reference the field name rather than a specific instance of. Try this instead:

```
  $fileFails = File::where('status', '=', '0')->get();
```

I hope this helps!